# FFMPEG failing to render PNGs as ProRes 4444

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I have a series of PNGs with transparent background that I would like to render as a video with an alpha channel. I tried running the following `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -i frames/%04d.png -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 4 -pix_fmt yuva444p10le video.mov
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Quicktime can't open the video and when I try to import it into DaVinci Resolve it's treated as corrupt. Is there some other parameter that I'm missing?

I'm running FFMPEG version 4.4.1. Here's the full output when I run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1_4 --enable-shared 
  --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= 
  --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl 
  --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame 
  --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband 
  --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora 
  --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx 
  --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 
  --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype 
  --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
  --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex 
  --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack 
  --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
```

Comment: So ffmpeg creates the video without errors but when you open it on quicktime it doesn't open? Is the size of the video as expected? Can you open it anywhere else like using VLC?

Comment: @RicardoBohner the video opens in VLC played but I can't import it into DaVinci Resolve. It things it's corrupted or something.